# What if objects can print themselves in Ruby? [Object#print]

Tags: ruby

I was thinking wouldn't it be cool to have a print method defined in the Ruby `Object` class? Consider the following:

```
class Object
  def print
    puts self.to_s
  end
end

23.times &:print
```

Is there any issue in having something like this? Seems like a good feature to have. It also appears easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with adding methods to `Object` is that they become universal and may clash with similarly named methods in other libraries or in your project.

There are already multiple simple ways to output data or convert to string form in Ruby core, so the risk of a clash (on a very useful method name) likely outweighs any benefits from nicer syntax even in your own code.

If you have a smaller set of classes in your own project, where you feel this would be a useful feature to have, then this is an ideal use case for mix-ins.

Define a module:

```
module CanPrintSelf
  def print
    puts self.to_s
  end
end
```

And include it in any class you want to have the feature:

```
class MyClass
  include CanPrintSelf
end

my_object = MyClass.new

my_object.print
```

So *you* can have this feature if you like it, and you don't need to modify Object.

Comment: Thanks, but will an object with print method be replaced by this definition? Since the method look up will stop at an earlier level when the definition is matched.

Comment: @JikkuJose: Could you re-phrase that, or give some code? No objects are replaced at any point, and I am not clear what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, to have confused you. Let me try to explain with an example: Imagine there is a `Printer` class with a method `print`. I am assuming you are talking about a clash in such a scenario, but I believe it will not be an issue as `Object` is much down the line in method lookup. If any higher classes has the method defined it will be called and method lookup will not reach the monkey patched definition in `Object`.

For instance: http://pastebin.com/HBwpjjWJ

The method definition of `print` in `Object` is not overriding the expected behavior of the the `Printer` class. Hope I am clear now?

Comment: Ah yes I understand now, thank you. The problem would occur if *you* expect to use your syntax with an Enumerator containing `Printer` objects - you would invoke the wrong method.

Comment: Umm, yes! Get it, but still I felt it looked better that puts object :)

Answer (score 3):

There's already [`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-inspect) defined. Plus, there's already [`Kernel#print`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-p) defined as private method in `Object` class and every class that inherits from it.

---

Comment: Also `p` covers OP's use case nicely when debugging or instrumenting code temporarily, and `irb` does it by default. In addition `"#{object}"` will invoke `object.to_s`

Comment: @NeilSlater I think I should make it clear: I am not looking for a way to pass the object and print the result. I am specifically excited for the capability to pass the method as a proc to any enumerator and quickly see its internal representation. Though this may be more intensive, I feel it looks very readable.

Comment: @JikkuJose: You can inspect an enumerator like this `p 23.times.to_a` - with the advantage that Ruby internal type indicators will also appear. This works because `.to_a` is included in `Enumerator`

Comment: Yes, I understand that @NeilSlater; but I was stressing on the way the call is happening. Rather than passing the object to a method that does the printing, have the object itself print. I also feel the code looks more readable the way I suggested?

Comment: @JikkuJose: I don't really see any extra readability, and it seems very niche to me. But if you are looking for critique, you may be better off posting to codereview.stackexchange.com - the question is in some ways borderline between SO and that site. On Stack Overflow, you are likely to get direct answers to "Is there any issue in having something like this?", not critique . . . my answer is definitely focused on outing the issue that I saw, and I tried to avoid expressing a style preference.

Answer (score 1):

This method already exists in the Ruby standard library. However, it has a different name: [`display`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-display).

```
23.times &:display

# 012345678910111213141516171819202122
```

As you can see, it does not write a newline after the object's string representation; it is ill-suited for object inspection.

Comment: I think it would have been great if it added a newline? Any idea why it avoids it?